# Button disappears when another is clicked

Tags: java, android

I have an app with 6 buttons that, when clicked, display strings with different lengths:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
    android:text=""
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/atbutt"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/namebutt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:onClick="changename"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/titlebutt"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/descbutt"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/titlebutt"
    android:layout_width="103dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="changetitle"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/descbutt"
    android:layout_width="126dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:onClick="changedesc"
    android:text="Description"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/titlebutt"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/namebutt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/urlbutt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="Url"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/contbutt"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/namebutt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/atbutt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="133dp"
    android:text="Publish Date"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/namebutt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/contbutt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="Content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/urlbutt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titlebutt" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I click namebutt, titlebutt or descbutt ( the only ones that have the onClick function at the moment), atbutt just disappears with no errors.

The onClicks:

```
 public void changename(View view){
    textView.setText(null);

    for(int a=0; a<articles.size(); a++) {

        textView.append(articles.get(a).nam);
    }

}

public void changetitle(View view){
    textView.setText(null);

    for(int a=0; a<articles.size(); a++) {
        textView.append(articles.get(a).titl);
    }

}

public void changedesc(View view){
    textView.setText(null);

    for(int a=0; a<articles.size(); a++) {
        textView.append(articles.get(a).desc);
    }

}
```

This only happens to atbutt

PS: I'm sorry for my choice in naming my buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of this attribute of `atbutt`:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
```

which means that the start of `atbutt` is at the end of the `TextView` and as the `TextView` grows it eliminates `atbutt`'s size.

Change to something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/atbutt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="133dp"
    android:text="Publish Date"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/urlbutt"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/namebutt" />
```